# I would like to achieve the following layout using CSS

Tags: c#, css

I do not want to use tables. I want to make a styling file, such that it can be applied to all pages I want.

It's like a template, using css

### note

I am a beginner using this "css" yes there are numerous tutorials, that's the main  problem. Please give specific examples and links which would help.

Also, is it possible to make the above template such that the controls exceeding the width of the cell are wrapped? meaning grow in length but stay within width limits? It should be

- page divided into three columns, left right and center
- center the biggest and left right of equal width
- these columns divided into six rows
- all rows of equal width initially

and,

- a way to place controls within the cells obtained from the above

Comment: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/

Comment: what would happen, if i replace the html div's by asp.panels? would the styling still work, or is there a catch?

Comment: I'm not an ASP person, but I assume that the asp.panel is just a proxy for a Div in this instance -- it is really just outputting the HTML you ask it to? If you install the IE developer tools or Firebug on Firefox you will be able to view and debug the rendered output.

Comment: okay thanks for the link solved every problem.

Comment: This old question is far too broad, even for the posting guidelines that were in force in 2010. It is essentially "teach me CSS".

Answer (score 1):

have a look a [960.gs](http://960.gs/) or dl directly from [here](http://www.spry-soft.com/grids/grid.css?column_width=60&column_amount=12&gutter_width=20). It gives you a lot of flexibility. It does take some time to get used to though if CSS is not your thing - however it's pretty simple once you get to grips with the classes. However, for the most part using 960.gs is plug and play IMO. There are other variations available that also define grids based on liquid layouts compared to the fixed approach of 960.gs

So in your case you probably will use `grid_2` and `grid_8` CSS classes to give you the columns. However, you actually should start by declaring rows rather than columns - which I think will give you the equal rows you are after.

```html
<div id="mainContent">
    <div class="clear"></div> 
    <div class="container_12" id="row1">
        <div class="grid_2"></div>
        <div class="grid_8"></div>
        <div class="grid_2"></div>
    </div>

    <-- other row declarations here -->

   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="container_12" id="row6">
       <div class="grid_2"></div>
       <div class="grid_8"></div>
       <div class="grid_2"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```